# Parse: push notification GCM Android not delivered via Parse

Tags: android, rest, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, parse-server

I was able make to make push notification is working. I tested it on REST.

```
POST
Host: android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=**apiKey**
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b33c61dc-a779-9198-bd96-aaf6c24fac6c

{
  "data": {
      "message": "hello world"
  },
  "registration_ids" : ["**deviceToken**"]
}
```

and my device got notification. Now I'm struggling to make parse push working.

```
POST localhost:7002/server/push
X-Parse-Application-Id: SSShop
X-Parse-Master-Key: 123
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "where": {},
  "data": {
      "alert": "hello world 123"
  }
}
```

the output: `{ result: true }`, but notification is not received on device. Trying send push notification via Parse Dashboard and got output like this:

```
verbose: sending push to 2 installations
verbose: sent push! 0 success, 0 failures.
```

**server.js:**

```
const instance = {
  appId:            'SSShop',
  port:             7002,
  serverURL:        'http://localhost:7002/server',
  masterKey:        '123',
  databaseURI:      'mongodb://docker/ssshop',
  publicServerURL:  'http://localhost:7002/server',
  mountPath:        '/server',
  verifyUserEmails: true,
  appName:          'SSShop',
  emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'XX',
      domain:      'XX',
      apiKey:      'XX'
    }
  },
  push: {
    android: {
      senderId: "92014XXXXX",
      apiKey: "**apiKey**"
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
"parse": "~1.8.5",
"parse-dashboard": "~1.0.13",
"parse-server": "~2.2.11",
```

checking node_modules and got parse-server-push-adapter use version 1.0.4.

Comment: Parse is currently shutting down, so I would advise you use something else like FCM (previously GCM) instead. See shut down notice here: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: Thanks @ArthurThompson for the reply. By the way I already use Parse Server. I'm still curious how to configure Parse Server to use Parse Push natively :)

Comment: Didn't know you were already using parse, assumed (wrongly) you were testing it out, I'm not aware of the inner workings of parse though :)